# How to Remove New Products Block products Price for store 1 not for store 2

Tags: magento-1.9, price, multistore, new-products

I need to remove home Page New product products price for store 1, not for store 2. if i remove

```
<!--   <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?> -->
```

Both stores do not display price of New Products, how to remove the price of new products in store 1 not store 2.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't comment the code just add it in condition**

Something like below

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
 if($storeId!=1)
 {
   echo  $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ;
 }
```

Here I assumed store id 1 you need to check your store id.

Comment: Pls correct me, https://justpaste.it/1evqa

Comment: a couple of times displaying price.

Comment: replace 
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?>  
with 
<?php

$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
 if($storeId!=1)
 {
   echo  $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ;
 }

?>

Comment: But in my main store displaying a couple of times, and my additional store displaying single time.

Comment: you mean price block is displayed two times?

Comment: yes, in my main store displaying two times, but in my additional store displaying single time.

Comment: seems you didnt replaced  echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ;
as in screen shot you sent both lines.
remove first one which is not in if condition

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70720/discussion-between-zus-and-satya-prakash-patel).